# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars with a function and an array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array, let's call it e:

```
e=[1,2,3]
```

And I include it in a function:

```
def f(x,y):
 return (69+e[x]*g(x)*y)/(420+g(x)*y)
```

where `g(x)` is a function I have defined earlier. Now, I want to do a contour plot, so I define:

```
x=[0,1,2]
y=np.linspace(69,420,69420)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

fig, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.contour(X,Y,G(X,Y),levels=[420.69],colors='black')
```

This is basically what I want to do, how can I debug this? Or is there a better way to program what I want to do?

Edit: Oh, I mistyped. I actually have `e[int(x)]` inside the function, not just `e[x]`

Edit: I meant to simplify my question by using a "simplified" form of my code, but it seems like some people are interested in the whole thing.

Instead of the `f(x,y)` I am actually using:

```
def Nseen(x,y):
return (0.147*8.815*10**(-6)+e[int(x/5-16)]*y*G(x)*2*y*GW(x))/(4.1/1000+y*G(x))*26340*20.3
```

Where `G(x)` and `GW(x)` are themselves other functions which depend on other functions, let me paste the entire code here:

```
def a(x,m):
return (x**2-m**2)**2*(x**2+2*m**2)

def b(x,m):
return 6*(x**2-m**2)*m**2

def c(x,m):
return 3*(x**2-2*m**2)

def f1(x,m,g):
return -2*x**2*(x**2-2*m**2)+(a(x,m)+c(x,m)*g**2*m**2)/(g*m)*(np.arctan((x**2-m**2)/(g*m))-np.arctan((-m**2)/(g*m)))-1/2*(b(x,m)+2*g**2*m**2)*np.log((g**2*m**2+(x**2-m**2)**2)/(g**2*m**2+m**4))

def f(x,m,g):
return f1(x,m,g)*(m**4/(96*x**8))

def GW(x):
return GF**2*x**5/(np.pi**3)*(f(x,MW,GW))

def G(x):
return GF*MH*x**2/(4*np.sqrt(2)*np.pi)*(1-x**2/MH**2)**2
```

And these are all the numbers I am using:

```
GF=1.1663787*10**(-5)
S2TH=0.23122
MW=80.378
MZ=91.1876
MH=125.18
GW=2.085
GZ=2.4952
```

And I am using:

```
e = [0.007400,0.002300,0.000600,0.01840,0.06040,0.09570,0.1412,0.1718,0.1718]
```

And

```
x = np.linspace(80,120,9)
y = np.linspace(10**(-8),10,1000)
```

Comment: you passes an array somewhere in your function while it should be a single value. you need to share the whole code and show the line that gives this error!

Comment: what is `e[x]` here?...you can't pass a whole array as index. Please post what `g(x)` is.

Comment: @MohamedAfify You're right! I actually have e[int(x)] in my code, I mistyped.

Comment: @Priya "e" is the array. e[int(x)] should call the xth element of the array. e[0]=1, e[1]=2, e[2]=3. And g(x) is a complicated function I have defined earlier. I don't think it should be that relevant.

Comment: I understand that `e[x]` should call the `xth element` provided `x` is a `temporary variable` that holds the `array index`, but where is the loop that uses `x` as the `array index`? so `e[x] = e[[0,1,2]] and g(x) = g[[0,1,2]]` output is ??

Comment: how is `f()` called in your code? Is the `x` parameter passed to `f()` the same as `x=[0,1,2]` in your follow on code? We really need to seem more of your code. This might also be a good excuse to use more meaningful variable names.

Comment: @Priya yes, that's what I am trying to do

Comment: @JonSG my functions are
`def Nseen(x,y):
 return (0.147*8.815*10**(-6)+e[int(x/5-16)]*y*G(x)*2*y*GW(x))/(4.1/1000+y*G(x))*26340*20.3`

`def G(x):
 return GF*MH*x**2/(4*np.sqrt(2)*np.pi)*(1-x**2/MH**2)**2`

`def GW(x):
 return GF**2*x**5/(np.pi**3)*(f(x,MW,GW))` 

`def f1(x,m,g):
 return -2*x**2*(x**2-2*m**2)+(a(x,m)+c(x,m)*g**2*m**2)/(g*m)*(np.arctan((x**2-m**2)/(g*m))-np.arctan((-m**2)/(g*m)))-1/2*(b(x,m)+2*g**2*m**2)*np.log((g**2*m**2+(x**2-m**2)**2)/(g**2*m**2+m**4))

def f(x,m,g):
 return f1(x,m,g)*(m**4/(96*x**8))` 

And well... `a(x,m)`, `b(x,m)`, and `c(x,m)`don't fit

Comment: @pollux33 [edit] your question to add new details.

Answer (score 0):

Your error can be distilled down to:

```
import numpy

x = numpy.linspace(80,120,9)
e = [1,2,3]
print(e[int(x)])
```

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

This is because `x` is a numpy array and cannot be used as an index into a list. Note:

```
print(x)
```

is going to give you something like:

```
[ 80.  85.  90.  95. 100. 105. 110. 115. 120.]
```

I'm not actually sure what you hope to index `e` with, perhaps you might try:

```
e[int(x[0])]
```

This is not really an answer and I will delete it after you reply to it but there was too much here to type for a comment.

Comment: I'm trying to index `e` to values between 80 and 120. What I want is that the first element of the array (0.007400) corresponds to a value of 80, the second to 85... This is because of the other functions, namely `GW(x)` and `G(x)`, that do depend on these explicit numbers.

Comment: Are you attempting to get all the values of `e` between indexes 80 and 120? Such that you might do `e[x[0]: x[-1]]`? Or are you looking to create a dictionary such that `{x[0]: e[0]}` by potentially `zip(e, x)`?  I still cannot tell

Comment: If this code simplification encapsulates you issue, you might want to edit your question to just use it as it will be much easier for people to understand and help you.  That way I can delete this 1/2 answer.

Comment: If what you want is a list of `[e[80], e[85]...e[120]]` then you can `[e[i] for i in x]`